# How to create a Update function in Java

Tags: java, game-loop

I have recently started using Java, but have been programming in javascript, and actionscript 3 for a while.

I am used to the language giving me the ability to simply do something like:

```
private function Update(){
//stuff
}
```

or something similar to that.

I am looking for something similar in Java, and I want to make sure I am doing it correctly.

I started following a tutorial, and they said to do something like this:

```
 long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                delta--;
            }

            if(running)
                render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
```

This seems to be every second calling the tick() function, not the same as every frame though, and while things tend to happen in less time than a second, I would much rather use the same old frame by frame method i was using. (Unless someone can give me a reason not to, always up for an opinion)

So I am wondering, why not just do something like:

```
while(running){
Update();
}
```

I believe this would call every frame. Am I doing something completely crazy here? is there a much better method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `tick()` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nuance here. You asked:

> So I am wondering, why not just do something like:
>
> while(running){
>   Update();
>   }
>
> I believe this would call every frame.

This is false. If you place your *Update()* method inside a simple *while(true)* loop, it will be called **as much times as the processor can handle**. If your processor can run it 123456 times a second, it will.

The method the tutorial you follow is using is called a **fixed time-step update**. In other words, **you call your *Update()* function X times a second** (often 60) at fixed intervals (1/60 or 0.0166... seconds).

By using a simple *while(true)* loop, you can use a technique called a **delta-time update**. This technique calls the *Update()* functions as many times as it can, but passes the **time elapsed between 2 loops to the *Update()* function**, so that you can make your calculations accordingly.

There is a lot of documentation on the various advantages and disadvantages of both methods, a quick Google search or a search on this site should give plenty information. But nobody can tell you which one is the ABSOLUTE better.

**NOTE**: In your example, the *Update()* function is only running 1 time per second. You'd need to change a line in order to have the 60 updates per second you want:

```
delta += (now - lastTime) / ns / amountOfTicks;
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the tick function outside the while loop and next to the render function
Then you can even make a whole new function with render and tick if you want.

```
While (running)

{

Render ();

Tick ();

}
```